# 3D modelling with DEMs and ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, dem, 3d-map, qgis2threejs, three-js

I am trying and right now in the search of methods to visualize 3D terrain with the use of the JS framework "ThreeJS" and so far I have only got through to visualizing with the QGIS2threeJS plugin which only produces a TIN model object which the resolution is not quite acceptable. While I am on the search for more methods because I might have missed something, I want to know that is there a way to import the Open Topography DEM data or any other source into your own model and visualize them in different resolutions using JS and/or other ways because this project is later going to be integrated with a portal and I need the flexibility of developing from scratch.